# alternative algorithm for the activity selection

Tags: pseudocode

I have a problem where I need to determine if the following pseudocode solves the activity selection problem optimally (eg. no overlapping events while getting the maximum number of activities). 
 [image]

I have gone through a few tries on paper with it and with the tried and true version i see which is by sorting the activities by ending time and it seems to work, but i am suspicious. Can anyone point me in the right direction to find a definitive proof if this does or doesnt work?

Comment: Is there any consideration to the total time spent in an activity? for example are 2 hour long activities and 4 half hour long activities equivilant? Or is the latter more because 4 > 2?

Comment: the latter is more since its about booking the maximum number of activities. I cant figure out how to prove/disprove it, and i havent found any mention of this algo so i have a feeling it doesnt uphold the optimal solution

Comment: Well there are many such greedy algorithms that are optimal, and I have a feeling this one is. I've drawn up three posts already that disprove it only to find fault logic in my disproof.

Comment: im in the same boat, but i know i cant put down that its optimal just on a hunch and its bothering me that i cant think of something concrete to put down on paper

Comment: if it is not already to late this site explains   http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Greedy/actSelectionGreedy.htm